# Mixed-Content on amp-list

Tags: amp-html

I have a site served over https and I'm trying to implement AMP. But when I use amp-list I get a mixed-content error. I tried both relative paths and direct urls for the src but both give me the mixed-content error. Currently my amp-list looks like this:

```
<amp-list reset-on-refresh="always" layout="responsive" height="1000" width="500" [height]="items.length" src="https://domain.to/json?parameter=value" binding="refresh">
```

The error I get is

```
The page at 'https://domain.to/amp/page' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://domain.to/json?parameter=value&__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.to'
```

I tried searching the source code of my page for hard-coded http but everything is either relative or https. So now I'm at a lost at what to do.

Answer (score 0):

`http://domain.to/json?parameter=value&__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.to` is loaded via HTTP. Access the page directly in your browser and redirect it to HTTPS.